# onclick javascript function not working on a div element

Tags: javascript, css

I recently started learning coding and this is what i tried and got stuck at. The Javascript code functionality (on click) does not work on the div element. Anything wrong with the code? please help!

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        var start = new Date().getTime();
        document.getElementById("rectangle").oncick = function() {
        document.getElementById("rectangle").style.display = "none";
        var end = new Date().getTime();
        var timetaken = (end - start) / 1000;
        document.getElementById("timetaken").innerHTML = timetaken + "s";

     }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO! You have `oncick` instead of `onclick` :)

Answer (score 0):

If you could post the rest of your code, it would help, but right off-hand I see that your onclick is misspelled as "oncick"

Honestly, take a look at the Console when running this in any modern web browser.  You should see this as an error in the code right away.

Also, take a look at the jQuery framework -- it'll really tighten up the code here and helps minimize a lot of the grunt work.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

misspell of onClick,use vscode and few plugins for better coding.